# Transformable and Magical Record

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord, transformable

Can I use transformable with Magical Record ? 
 Because when I use transformable then my app crash  So I so confuse about thing Which can use transformable with Magical Record?

Comment: There are no details to your question, only suggesting that MagicalRecord crashes your app when you use transformable attributes. Since this is a core data feature, it's likely you are not setting this feature up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use transformables with magical record. I've done so in several projects. Please post more information on your crash so we can attempt to help you.